# Iteralting two lists simultaneously

Tags: java, jpa

I have scenario like this

```
List<ValidityCommerceRegion> myinputList= new ArrayList<ValidityCommerceRegion>();

public class ValidityCommerceRegion {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ValidityCommerceRegionPK id;
}
```

And in my pk class I have like this

```
public class ValidityCommerceRegionPK {

    @Column(name="VALIDITY_ID")
    private Long validityId;

    @Column(name="COMMERCE_ID")
    private Long commerceId;

    @Column(name="REGION_ID")
    private String regionId;

}
```

now in my input list in have 156 be and 155 be coming and from

the db I am getting the list of all records containing validity commerce region

like this

```
List<ValidityCommerceRegion> vacoreList = validityCommerceRegionDlService.findAll();
```

now how to get the particular validity id  of the input list passed

my db structure and required output

Comment: I don't get what you actually want to achieve. Compare 2 lists? Combine them?

Comment: i want to get validityid of the input list

Comment: Which list? Please edit the question and try to be as specific as possible (in which line do you want to get which object)?